# Criar select com varias condições

Tags: postgresql, query

Possuo uma tabela com diversos registro de ligações e necessito realizar algumas condições, para separar registros.

Já utilizo o select para validar as informações

```
SELECT  count(*) as qtdade_status_dia,

        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".contrato || "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".telefone || "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".data_registro AS contrato_telefone_data_registro,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".data_registro,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".contrato,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".telefone,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".tipo_discagem,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".status_telefonia

        FROM "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO"
        GROUP BY 

        contrato_telefone_data_registro,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".data_registro,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".contrato,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".telefone,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".tipo_discagem,
        "TB_BASE_ACIONAMENTO".status_telefonia

        HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
```

A  partir desta consulta que na verdade é uma view faço consultas nela.

Precisaria contar o campo status_telefonia juntamente com as regras acima para depois realizar um select semelhante ao abaixo:

```
 SELECT * FROM "public"."VW_BS_TESTE" 

 WHERE "status_telefonia" = ' MACHINE' 

 OR "status_telefonia" = ' INVALID NUMBER' 

 AND "qtdade_status_dia" > '5' 

 AND "status_telefonia" NOT LIKE '% HANDLED%'

 AND  "data_registro" >= '01/01/2017' 

 AND "data_registro" <= '23/02/2017' 

 AND "tipo_discagem" = 'OUTBOUND'
```

Se não achar o resultar na consulta acima faria a consulta seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."VW_BS_TESTE" 

WHERE "status_telefonia" = ' BUSY' 

AND "qtdade_status_dia" >= '3' 

AND "status_telefonia" NOT LIKE '% HANDLED%'

AND  "data_registro" >= '01/01/2017' 

AND "data_registro" <= '23/02/2017' 

AND "tipo_discagem" = 'OUTBOUND'
```

Gostaria de criar uma query que fizesse em um único processo para agilizar o processo. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

[image: Modelo da Tabela]

Comment: Com o UNION ele reconhece apenas o primeiro SELECT, fora que precisaria também agrupar Status_Telefonia para realizar a consulta antes, não teria como usar algum tipo de condição ?